# Measuring true length of polyline over terrain in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, terrain, length

I use QGIS for a variety of mapping purposes and also for managing UAV/drone data. I need to calculate the true length of a mapped fence over varying terrain for which i have a detailed DEM.

Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please, take the [tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) and [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/263989/edit) your question. What have you tried so far? You can achieve this in a variety of processes, so be more specific about your research

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  For your questions to be answered here they should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.